# Calculating the representative/average group of categorical data

Tags: excel-formula

I have a summary dataset below with 3 variables:

| Rating | Frequency | Total Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 2 | $10000 |
| B | 15 | $24003 |
| C | 5 | $56789 |
| ... |  |  |

There are 18 different rating categories each with varying frequencies and values. I need to workout the average group which the data falls into so which of the rating groups is the average in both frequency and total value, so in short the data is rating group B for example.

I'm sure there must be a proper way to do this but haven't been able to easily find the answer online.

I've tried calculating some kind of weighted average but struggling as each category would be equally weighted?

Comment: `=SUMPRODUCT(B2:B4,C2:C4)/SUM(B2:B4)` would get you weighted average, but what do you want to do with it from there on? A group does not fall in the average, but is part of it. The outcome may be closest to a group's value. Is that what you're after?

Comment: Yes this is what I've tried but didn't really know how to apply the result. I want to say what rating is my data as a whole, so given all the values & frequencies whether my data can be rated as A, B, OR C.

Answer (score 0):

In **Office 365** you could use:

```
=LET(range,A2:C4,
     rating,INDEX(range,,1),
     freq,INDEX(range,,2),
     total,INDEX(range,,3),
     w_avg,SUMPRODUCT(freq,total)/SUM(freq),
     delta,BYROW(total,LAMBDA(t,
                 MAX(t,w_avg)-MIN(t,w_avg))),
INDEX(rating,XMATCH(MIN(delta),delta)))
```

It requires the three columns as an input and names the columns. Than it calculates the weighted average as in my comment.
Then it checks the difference between the total and the weighted average per row. Than it indexes the `rating` and matches the one with the smallest difference (closest match to weighted average).

Note: in case of ties this would result in the first listed as a result. Otherwise we need to use FILTER.

For **older Excel** I have a solution including a helper cell & column:

In cell `E2` use: `=SUMPRODUCT(B2:B4,C2:C4)/SUM(B2:B4)` to calculate the weighted average.

In cell `D2` use: `=MAX(C2,$E$2)-MIN(C2,$E$2)` and drag this down to the last used row in your range to calculate the difference between the total of the rating and the weighted average.

In cell `F2` use: `=INDEX(A2:A4,MATCH(MIN(D2:D4),D2:D4),0)`

To match the rating of the smallest difference.

Or this one line monster:

```
=INDEX(A2:A4,
       MATCH(
             MIN( 
                 IF(C2:C4>=SUMPRODUCT(B2:B4,C2:C4)/SUM(B2:B4),
                    C2:C4,    
                    SUMPRODUCT(B2:B4,C2:C4)/SUM(B2:B4))- 
                 IF(C2:C4<=SUMPRODUCT(B2:B4,C2:C4)/SUM(B2:B4),
                    C2:C4, 
                    SUMPRODUCT(B2:B4,C2:C4)/SUM(B2:B4))), 
             IF(C2:C4>=SUMPRODUCT(B2:B4,C2:C4)/SUM(B2:B4),
                C2:C4, 
                SUMPRODUCT(B2:B4,C2:C4)/SUM(B2:B4))- 
             IF(C2:C4<=SUMPRODUCT(B2:B4,C2:C4)/SUM(B2:B4),
                C2:C4,             
                SUMPRODUCT(B2:B4,C2:C4)/SUM(B2:B4)),
             0))
```

Comment: I can't seem to get this working, I've directly pasted in your formula and adjusted the appropriate ranges but getting a #NAME? error

Comment: Ah, this requires Office 365

Comment: See my edit for a solution that would work for older Excel